# Unusually large number of votes?

Tags: support, voting, votes

Today, there was an unusual number of upvotes for me! (On different subjects). Was it someone being benevolent?

Previously, I have had an unusual number of downvotes, which were found to be from the same individual, probably with a grudge. Is there any way to find out who the donor was, or is that information a secret for mods, or completely kept from everyone? Curious.

Comment: If they're all from one person, it'll probably be corrected by the system within 24 hours. But mods can't access this information, only staff can: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12985/938841

Comment: While we encourage people to vote on posts not users, sometimes folks will see a good (or bad) post and look at others by that same person, and then vote. Wait and see if the votes are reversed. If so, they were probably all from 1 person.

Comment: Your score today doesn't seem out of line with the usual ebb and flow of overall voting. So, yes, an unusual number of different posts voted on, but overall seems harmless. I've seen the same thing from time to time in my own reputation. Sometimes those votes all get removed, other times not.